# HornetQ 2.2.5 Embeded Example Exception

Tags: jms, hornetq

I am new to HornetQ and I am testing hornetQ Examples. I am getting Exception while running the example EmbeddedExample.java(resides in : hornetq-2.2.5.Final\examples\core\embedded\src\org\hornetq\core\example). I had made some change in that example and getting Exception. The changes I had made is, I had put sending process and consuming process in a for loop of 1,00,000 iteration. 
The code is:

```
System.out.println("Producer:");
System.out.println("StartDate: "+new Date());
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{   
    message.putStringProperty(propName, "Message: " + i);
    producer.send(message);             
}
System.out.println("EndDate: "+new Date());
// Step 7. Create the message consumer and start the connection
ClientConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queueName);

session.start();

// Step 8. Receive the message.
System.out.println("Consumer:");
System.out.println("StartDate: "+new Date());

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)            
{   
    ClientMessage messageReceived = messageConsumer.receive();
    System.out.println(messageReceived.getStringProperty(propName));
}
System.out.println("EndDate: "+new Date());
```

Producer works fine,and consumer gives me an exception after reading 18K or 13K msges. The stack trace is:

```
[java] Message: 18384
[java] Sep 2, 2011 11:15:29 AM org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate
info
[java] INFO: HornetQ Server version 2.2.5.Final (HQ_2_2_5_FINAL_AS7, 121) [
588e32ee-d493-11e0-b759-0026b6a94d9b] stopped
[java] HornetQException[errorCode=102 message=Consumer is closed]
[java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.checkClosed(C
lientConsumerImpl.java:811)
[java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(Clien
tConsumerImpl.java:163)
[java]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(Clien
tConsumerImpl.java:364)
[java]     at org.hornetq.core.example.EmbeddedExample.main(EmbeddedExample
.java:107)
[java] Java Result: -1

BUILD FAILED
C:\hornetq-2.2.5.Final\examples\core\embedded\build.xml:40: EmbeddedExample
```

How do I overcome from this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example will start a VM with 50M only, and on your example you are sending 100K messages, what will probably not be enough for the 50M.

I don't have your changes here, but I could run the example with 100K messages given providing more memory on the build.xml.

You were probably getting a few exceptions before what interrupted the communication and made the session to close.

Also, Message systems are asynchronously, so I propose you to change your sending block to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{ 
    message = sesison.createMessage(true); // move it   
    message.putStringProperty(propName, "Message: " + i);
    producer.send(message);             
}
```

And you should also ACK on the consuming. Otherwise the message will still be at the memory.

the intent of the example was to show how to embed HornetQ. For other usages such as acking and producing there are other examples.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)            
{   
    ClientMessage messageReceived = messageConsumer.receive();
    messageReceived.acknowledge();
    System.out.println(messageReceived.getStringProperty(propName));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clebert,
It works when I again start a session in consumer's loop. I have tried your suggession but its not working, the exception is still there.

Comment: you can see code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291648/how-to-make-a-queue-persisted-in-hornetq-2-2-5-core-client

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. You would need to send me the code that produces the exception. (I'm not sure the code you posted at the other question will produce the exception or not). So far I suspect you are running out of memory. (from the test I run)

Comment: where do I send you? my mail mail-id is news.anand11@gmail.com