# How to make a queue persisted in HornetQ 2.2.5 core client?

Tags: queue, hornetq

I want to make persisted queue in core hornetQ client. The problem is when I stop the server the queue and the data will be destroyed. How to make a queue persisted?
My code is:

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration;
import org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClientConsumer;
import org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClientMessage;
import org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClientProducer;
import org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClientSession;
import org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClientSessionFactory;
import org.hornetq.api.core.client.HornetQClient;
import org.hornetq.api.core.client.ServerLocator;
import org.hornetq.core.config.Configuration;
import org.hornetq.core.config.impl.ConfigurationImpl;
import org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMAcceptorFactory;
import org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory;
import org.hornetq.core.server.HornetQServer;
import org.hornetq.core.server.HornetQServers;

public class EmbeddedExample
{

   public static void main(final String[] args)
   {
      try
      {

         // Step 1. Create the Configuration, and set the properties accordingly
         Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
         configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(false);
         configuration.setSecurityEnabled(false);

         configuration.getAcceptorConfigurations().add(new TransportConfiguration(InVMAcceptorFactory.class.getName()));

         // Step 2. Create and start the server
         HornetQServer server = HornetQServers.newHornetQServer(configuration);
         server.start();

         // Step 3. As we are not using a JNDI environment we instantiate the objects directly
         ServerLocator serverLocator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(new TransportConfiguration(InVMConnectorFactory.class.getName()));
         ClientSessionFactory sf = serverLocator.createSessionFactory();        

         // Step 4. Create a core queue        
         ClientSession coreSession = sf.createSession(false, false, false);      

         final String queueName = "queue.exampleQueue";

         coreSession.createQueue(queueName, queueName, true);


         coreSession.close();

         ClientSession session = null;

         try
         {

            // Step 5. Create the session, and producer
            session = sf.createSession();

           ClientProducer producer = session.createProducer(queueName);

            // Step 6. Create and send a message
            ClientMessage message = session.createMessage(true);

            final String propName = "myprop";

            message.putStringProperty(propName, "Hello sent at " + new Date());

            System.out.println("Producer:");
            System.out.println("StartDate: "+new Date());
             for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
             {  
                   message = session.createMessage(true); // move it   
                    message.putStringProperty(propName, "Message: " + i);
                    producer.send(message);       
             }
            System.out.println("EndDate: "+new Date());
            // Step 7. Create the message consumer and start the connection
            ClientConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queueName);

            session.start();

            // Step 8. Receive the message.
            System.out.println("Consumer:");
            System.out.println("StartDate: "+new Date());

            //for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)         
             int i=0;
            while(true)
            {   
                 i++;
                 if(i == 10000){    
                     i=0;
                     session.start();
                     System.out.println("EndDate: "+new Date());                        
                 }
                 ClientMessage messageReceived = messageConsumer.receive(5000);
                 if (messageReceived!=null) messageReceived.acknowledge();
                 //System.out.println(messageReceived.getStringProperty(propName));
            }

         }
         finally
         {
            // Step 9. Be sure to close our resources!
            if (sf != null)
            {
               sf.close();
            }

            // Step 10. Stop the server
            server.stop();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not paste the code here? -- And does the configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(false) have something to do with the queue not being persisted? (Just a guess in the dark)

Comment: I have tried with  configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(true); but it gives me " java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"  exception.

Comment: Can you edit your original question by adding the code here? It would be much better for future references.. as nothing guarantee the paste.bin you made will live forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you disable persistence, you won't have persistence:

```
Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(true); <<<<  Make this true
```

The UnsatisfiedLinkError is probably because you select AIO and didn't have the native library on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, either set Journal or make the native library available in a Linux system.

```
configuration.setJournalType(JournalType.NIO);
```